# DFT Vs DCT - spectrum differences

Tags: dft, dct

When you are transforming a signal in to a frequency domain using both DFT and DCT, say for a function sin(x), how the spectrum will be? will both frequency values (of DCT and DFT) same? Can anyone explain the values of the frequencies for the function sin(x) (obviously the frequency should be 1/2π)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DCT for a signal $x(t)$ on $[0,T]$ is roughly the same as the DFT for the function $x(|t|)$ on $[-T,T]$, that is, mirrored at the vertical axis. Since that function is even, all sine coefficients will be zero and can be removed from the result.

Now $\sin(|t|)$ is different from $\sin(t)=-\sin(-t)$ for negative $t$, so the resulting coefficients will be quite unrelated. If the sampling interval ends at $t=T=2\pi$, the DFT will only exhibit one peak around frequency $f=\frac1{2\pi}$.

But because of the kink at $t=0$ in $\sin(|t|)$, and a second at the end of the sampling interval, the DCT will exhibit a general background of size $f^{-2}$ in the coefficient for frequencies $f>0$.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, DFT produces complex valued outputs, therefore, you better compare its magnitude with magnitude of DCT whose input and output are both real.

As you may know, DCT can be exactly computed from DFT; therefore you can find DCT[k] value for any k, from the DFT[k] values of the pre-processed x[n] signal.

DCT is preferrable for those processes, such as speech or image coding, where low frequency content will be emphasized. For general spectral analysis purposes however, DFT yields a better tool, and mapping its results to physical frequencies is simpler. If you have matlab, check the following code to see if their difference is significant for you:

```
N=128; f = 123, Fs = 1024;   % set the signal parameters  
x = sin(2* pi* f*[0:N-1]/Fs);  % create a real signal x[n]  
figure,plot(abs(fft(x,N)));  % get the first half of it, since it is symmetric  
figure,plot(abs(dct(x,N)));  % get DCT for comparison
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform). There is an example image, but for DFT.

[image: DFT vs. DCT]